# JavaScript get text between round brackets ignoring inside brakets

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the text inside this bracket using regexp

```
var str = "func(arg(), arg)()";
str.match(/regex/)[0]; // Results "arg(), arg"
```

Comment: Regular expressions can't match balanced expressions like this.

Comment: I dont think this question as duplicatre